# Eventhandler in CefSharp DevTool class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, events, google-chrome-devtools, cefsharp

I'm trying to work with the Chrome DevTools Protocol in CefSharp. I tried out the example for DevTools. Calling methods is working perfectly.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/DevTools/DevToolsExtensions.cs

```
const string methodName = "Page.captureScreenshot";
var result = await devToolsClient.ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync(methodName);
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to work with events as well. e.g. "Network.dataReceived"
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/

I tried following:

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

public void InitializeChromium()
{
    chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://stackoverflow.com");

    this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    chromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += ChromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;
}

private void ChromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chromeBrowser.GetDevToolsClient().DevToolsEvent += OnDevToolsEvent;
    chromeBrowser.ShowDevTools();
}

private static void OnDevToolsEvent(Object source, DevToolsEventArgs e)
{
    //how to use that handler?
    //not called!
}
```

The "OnDevToolsEvent" is never called. Any ideas? :) And thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3158#issuecomment-657752330 you must enable the domain to receive events. You should also keep a reference to the DevToolsClient instance returned by GetDevToolsClient and Dispose of it when you are finished.

Comment: Great. That did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by using "Network.enable" which enables the handler. Thanks @amaitland

```
const string methodName = "Network.enable";
var result = await devToolsClient.ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync(methodName);
```